# How to get the ages that are greater than 50 in php

Tags: php, regex

Need to get all the age keys and count the number of them greater than 50. Given data

```
$data = '{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47"}';
```

Output should be 2 as there are 2 ages greater than 50

This is what I am trying

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);    
$strArray = explode(',', $array['data']);
$temp1 = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($strArray); $i++){
    $key_value = explode('=', $strArray[$i]);
    $temp1[$i][$key_value[0]] = $key_value[1];
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($temp1);
print "</pre>";
```

Output is coming as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => IAfpK
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ age] => 58
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ key] => WNVdi
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ age] => 64
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ key] => jp9zt
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ age] => 47
        )    
)
```

Need to get all the ages in an array to compare.

Comment: Why is your input data structured like that? I suggest get your data into an array structure that groups your values, then run array_filter on it with a custom function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: It is given in that format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple. Hope this will work for you,

```
$output = [];
$data = '{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47"}';
$array = json_decode($data, true);
foreach (explode(',',$array['data']) as $key => $value)
{
    if(str_contains($value,'age'))
    {
        $age = explode('=',$value);
        if($age[1] > 50)
        {
            array_push($output, $age[1]);
        }
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is truly semi-structured like that and isn’t too massive, and you want to keep the keys, I think this is a good case for `array_shift` to reduce the array until it is exhausted:

```php
$data = '{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47"}';
$array = json_decode($data, true);    
$strArray = explode(',', $array['data']);

$clean = [];
while(count($strArray) >= 2){
    $key = explode('=', array_shift($strArray))[1];
    $age = explode('=', array_shift($strArray))[1];
    $clean[$key] = (int)$age;
}

var_dump($clean);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/RIF2q

You should hopefully be able to add whatever logic you need to test ages then.

Comment: @user2159616  this is a better solution and I would suggest utilising this. When I first wrote my answer, I didn't even notice the key which is likely going to be needed to match the ages bigger than 50 back to whatever source you obtained the data from.

Answer (score 1):

An effective way to achieve this since your data is strangely formatted would be to use regex. For some reason, the `?:` non capturing group is still being captured so all of the ages will be in the second capture group of the match array - you can play to optimise that.

Once you have all your ages in an array, a simple `array_filter` for ages larger than 50 is more than enough. You can see a [live working example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/95Qea).

```
$data = '{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47"}';

preg_match_all('/(?:age=)([0-9]+)/', json_decode($data)->data, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

// Only continue if we found any ages in the string
if (array_key_exists(1, $matches))
{
    // 58, 64
    $greaterThan50 = array_filter($matches[1], fn($age) => intval($age) > 50);
}
```

Ofc, if you then need the corresponding key, you will need to do more magic.

If you're using less than PHP 7.4, arrow functions are not supported. You can instead replace `$greaterThan50` assignment to:

```
$greaterThan50 = array_filter($matches[1], function($age) {
    return intval($age) > 50;
});
```

[See it working live on 34vl.org](https://3v4l.org/vOTdh)

Comment: It's throwing Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: `=>` was introduced in PHP 7.4 as arrow functions. If you're using below 7.4 then you should probably upgrade for security reasons but you can always replace it with the following: `function($age) { return intval($age) > 50; }`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your logic, You can do it as follows :

```
<?php

$data = '{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47"}';

$array = json_decode($data, true);    
$strArray = explode(',', $array['data']);
$keys = array();
$ages = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($strArray); $i++){
    $key_value = explode('=', $strArray[$i]);
    if ((int)$key_value[1] > 0 ) {
        array_push($ages, $key_value[1]);
    } else {
        array_push($keys, $key_value[1]);
    }
}

$result = array_combine($keys, $ages);
$result = array_filter($result, function($age) {
    return intval($age) > 50;
});
print "<pre>";
print_r($result);
print "</pre>";
```